# How to assign large concatenated string and split it in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a concatenated string that i have taken as nvarchar(max)
but it is retrieving only 9998 characters only.

I want to get all the characters that are in the concatenated string.

How can I retrieve all the characters?

```
ALTER function [utils].[udf_SplitString] 

(
@iSearchText NVARCHAR(MAX)
,@iSearchExpr VARCHAR(10) 
)
Returns @Results Table(id integer identity,SearchText NVARCHAR(MAX),ElementValue VARCHAR(max))
As
BEGIN

Insert into @Results
(SearchText,ElementValue)
------- Split........
SELECT SearchText,
NullIf(SubString(SearchExpr + SearchText + SearchExpr , PositionedAt , CharIndex(SearchExpr , SearchExpr + SearchText + SearchExpr , PositionedAt) - PositionedAt) , '') AS SearchText
FROM (select numberid PositionedAt  from utils.numbers) Occurences, 
(
select 
@iSearchText as SearchText,
@iSearchExpr as SearchExpr
) dual
WHERE PositionedAt <= Len(SearchExpr + SearchText + SearchExpr) AND SubString(SearchExpr + SearchText + SearchExpr , PositionedAt - 1, 1) = SearchExpr 
AND CharIndex(SearchExpr , SearchExpr + SearchText + SearchExpr , PositionedAt) - PositionedAt > 0
------------ End of Split
Return

End
```

Comment: Show us the **full** code so we can see intermediate datatypes as I said in the previous question. You want an answer? Give us what we need to help you.

Comment: Here i am giving the datatype as nvarchar(max) but in the input it contains more than 9998 characters. if i use the above code i am able to retrieve only 9998 characters only. If i want to get all the characters in the input string what i have to do?

Comment: I said "full code". You have not shown us that the input is 9998 bytes: it could be correct (since it's >8000) but you can only get 9998 from adding the split values. Now, without the "split" code  we **can't help you** Do you understand?

Comment: How are you validating that it is 9998 characters? Are you returning results to some application and checking the length there? You know that something else in between the code and your check could be truncating the value at (probably 10000) characters, right?

Comment: Why is this upvoted? We can't explain why OP get 9998 bytes when we don't have the UDF code?

Comment: In the function we are inserting into the returned table

Comment: @Vara Prasad.M: and your "------- Split........" bit hides the code that is causing the 9998 bytes. **Give us full information**

Comment: actually the comma seperated values are our customerid's. we need to update the customerid status in the table. but if i use the above function it is updating only 888 records only. it is skipping all the other customers because the length of the input string to the user defined function

Comment: Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified - i am getting this message if i am sending the entire code?

Comment: @Vara -  You can edit the question instead of adding the code in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your split function is based the "numbers" table technique, using your `utils.numbers`?

What does this say?

```
SELECT COUNT(*), MAX(numberid) utils.numbers
```

Do you have enough numbers to deal with the full string length, potentially 1 billion because it is nvarchar(max)?

I suspect you have only 10000 rows which is causing your truncation. The 9998 comes from the last `,` position before you run out of numbers

Comment: yes it is getting only the 10000 rows only. so now what i have to change?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[ParseStringList]  (@StringArray nvarchar(max) )  
Returns @tbl_string Table  (ParsedString nvarchar(max))  As  

BEGIN 

DECLARE @end Int,
        @start Int

SET @stringArray =  @StringArray + ',' 
SET @start=1
SET @end=1

WHILE @end<Len(@StringArray)
    BEGIN
        SET @end = CharIndex(',', @StringArray, @end)
        INSERT INTO @tbl_string 
            SELECT
                Substring(@StringArray, @start, @end-@start)

        SET @start=@end+1
        SET @end = @end+1
    END

RETURN
END
```

Use it like this:

```
Select ParsedString From dbo.ParseStringList(@StringArray)
```

Comment: in the select parsedstring i will get only the 9998 characters right. if i use this function in any stored procedure i may not get all the characters that are given as input which it contains more than 9998 characters

Comment: I think nvarchar(max) will give you 4000 characters.  If you change it to varchar(max), you can get up to 8000 characters.  If you need anything larger than that, there are blob-types you can look into.

Comment: how can i assign the BLOB types?

Comment: BTW -- whatever datatype you use, you always have to subtract 2 from the size.  I.e., if you use varchar(max), the field-size is 8000 bytes, but the max size of the data you can store in that field is 8000 minus 2.